# Thymeleaf dynamic fields - checkbox, no hidden field generated

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I am using Thymeleaf (thymeleaf-spring4-2.1.3) with Spring MVC (4.1.1) and have a model / command object like this:

```
public class GenericEntity {
private Map<String, Object> properties = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
...
```

This is the relevant part of my thymeleaf template (simplified as i am generating the input type based on configuration):

```
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{properties[__${column.name}__]}" />
```

No hidden field is created for that checkbox even if it is of instance Boolean.

How does Thymeleaf determine that a hidden field has to be generated ?

Even if i change my properties to

```
private Map<String, Boolean> boolProps = new HashMap<String, Boolean>();
```

same here: no hidden field.

Comment: Are you sure it is binded well? I just tried simple bind on boolean value like: <input type="checkbox" class="skill" th:text="${komentar}" th:field="*{stays}"/> And the hidden field is there. Can you provide full template or at least this block where you iterate over?

Comment: Yes. Did some further investigation and i am quite sure that this is related to the preprocessing directive.

Comment: Martin , can ask u how u bind properties to base class in this example? I am trying to write down some fragments like to thymeleaf to drop rewrite entity props in view layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was actually a bug in thymeleaf-spring.

See - https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/71

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling yesterday with an exactly **opposite** problem and your post helped me to go into the right direction! Basically, thymeleaf was adding hidden field **always** and that broke my design.

I found your post and this post very useful:
https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/68

There is a comment that has been added 16 days ago from today (12 Dec 2014).

Looking at your code. Have you tried something very simple like adding another variable to your class:

```
private boolean test;
```

add getter and setter and then try to add it to to your template:

```
<input type="checkbox" th:field="*{test}" />
```

Check if this adds the hidden field.

I assume that you are not getting any compiler errors?
When I tried to use:

```
private Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

I **have to** add `th:value` to template.

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mapID" th:field="*{map['abc']}" th:value="123" />
```

And I get:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mapID" value="123" name="map['abc']">
<input type="hidden" name="_map['abc']" value="on">
```

I hope that this helps!

Comment: Thanks for elaborating ! For those who wanna have the hidden field **before** the checkbox field, add this line to `application.properties` :  
`spring.thymeleaf.render-hidden-markers-before-checkboxes=true`

source : https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf-spring/issues/178#issuecomment-466391471